# Redirect in Scala play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a problem with Redirect in Scala play framework.

How can I redirect to view BooksController.index() ? In documentation they suggest to use Redirect but I don't know how.

```
def edit(Id: Int) = Action {
    val book: Book = Book.findById(Id)
    Ok(views.html.edit())
  }

  def update = Action {
      implicit request =>
      val (id, title, price, author) = bookForm.bindFromRequest.get
      val book: Book = Book.findById(id)
      book.id = id
      book.title = title
      book.price = price
      book.author = author
      Redirect(routes.BooksController.index())
  }
```

Now can recognize --> import play.api.mvc.Results._ 
But i have an error --> "object java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect is not a value"

Answer (score 1):

If you would really like to continue using reverse routing in your code instead of having string uri values all over the place, see this:
[Redirect with Bad Request Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128526/redirect-with-bad-request-status).
The **Redirect** function accepts only a **String** or **Call**.
Try the following steps: 
 
0) Add in the **BookController**

```
import play.api.mvc._
```

1) Add the following string in your route config file(hard disk location: controllers/BooksController)

```
GET  /redirectedPage  controllers.BooksController.index
```

2) Define a variable in the **BookController**

```
val Home = Redirect(routes.BookController.index())
```

3) Describe in the **BookController**

```
def update = Action {
    implicit request => Home
}
```

Also do "sbt clean; sbt compile" to recompile auto-calls in ReverseRoutes.scala.
Well done.

Answer (score 0):

The last line in the `update` action is the `Redirect` call which redirects to BooksController `index` route

```
import play.api.mvc.Results._

Redirect(routes.BooksController.index())
```

Comment: Yes, but doesnt work for me. Cant recognize word Redirect

Comment: @Michael import `import play.api.mvc.Results._`

Comment: Thank you, now can recognize but i have an error "object java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect is not a value"